# copy-past tags to a dataset from a list of unique values in excel or openrefine

Tags: csv, tags, copy-paste, find-occurrences, openrefine

I'm working with a string dataset for which I defined a tag for each unique value in column 1.

Now I'd like to apply the corresponding tag for each occurrence of the unique value on excel, openrefine or python

For instance:

```
Column 1 (to)
100 Black Men of Greater Detroit, Inc
Column 10 (tag)
Minorities
```

For each time the `100 Black Men of Greater Detroit, Inc` appears in column 1, I'd like to make `minorities` appear in column 8.

Can a loop in excel, openrefine, or python do that?

Thanks for your help

[Here are the first raws of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEDO7.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are several different approaches you could take in OpenRefine.

**Approach 1:**

Facet on Column 1, choose the relevant value (e.g. "100 Black Men of Greater Detroit, Inc") and that will find all the rows where that value is contained in Column 1. Then update all cells in Column 8 to the value of the relevant tag.

**Approach 2:**

Transform the cells in Column 8 using a GREL statement like:

```
if(cells["Column 1"].value=="100 Black Men of Greater Detroit, Inc","minorities","")
```

There are probably some other approaches, and it may depend on how exactly you are deciding which tag to apply.

If these two approaches aren't what you need, feel free to expand on why not and how you need this to work or you